# After upgrading to jdk1.7.0_79 and 80 (linux only) getting java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate :keytool error

Tags: java, linux, ssl

I have upgraded from 1.7.0_51 to 1.7.0_79 and 80 on linux. I tried to import the SAME CERT and now am getting  the infamous:

```
java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate :keytool error
```

using this command:

```
/opt/java/bin/keytool -import -alias casdev -file /home/user/tomcat_cert.cer -keystore /opt/java/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

`/opt/java` is a symbolic link to `/opt/jdk1.7.0_80`

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Oh and one more thing, the import works fine on Windows!

Carl

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved.  when I transferred my certicate from windows machine to linux it did not copy fully.

it is now imported.